# How to reveal a GUI password hidden bellow asterisks or bullets?

Tags: x11, password, gui, gtk

On MS Windows we can une [Asterisk logger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/astlog.html), [Bullets password view](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html), [other tools](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-show-the-contents-of-password-fields/), [sandboy revelation](https://www.google.com/search?q=sandboy+revelation&hl=en), [showpw](http://www.scalabium.com/showpw.htm) or many other tools that can trace/change the GUI of an app...

How can we achieve the same on Linux? How can we uncover a hidden text of a GUI, GTK or else?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear because you don't specify the specific password field you are trying to view. Most applications allow you to see the password easily directly.

As for the rest of them, assuming they don't encrypt it, you may be able to find it in their configuration files.

Lastly, for browser password fields you can easily view 99% percent of them by removing the type from a password field directly from the code.

To do this right-click on the password field and choose `Inspect` or `Inspect Element`

You should now be presented with something like this.

```
<input class="something" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" id="password" />
```

Remove `password` from type so now it says

```
<input class="something" type="" autocomplete="off" name="password" id="password" />
```

*Note: That's a one time change refreshing the page will revert the changes.*